# Powershell How to export the XML file into Excel (CSV)

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to export this xml file into Excel (CSV). I have search online for some examples but I cant seem to find anything which can hep me.

I'm not good with powershell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products updated="12/16/2015">
  <product name="office">
    <addresslist type="IPv6">
      <address>2</address>
      <address>256</address>
      <address>434</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="IPv4">
      <address>13.107</address>
      <address>13.14/24</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="URL">
      <address>*.google</address>
      <address>*.yahoo</address>
      <address>*.some other link</address>
    </addresslist>
  </product>
  <product name="LYO">
    <addresslist type="URL">
      <address>*.rtrt</address>
      <address>eever</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="IPv4">
      <address>23.178</address>
      <address>23.18</address>
      <address>23.19</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="IPv6">
      <address>2a01:13::/4</address>
      <address>2a01:1</address>
    </addresslist>
  </product>
</products>
```

This is what I have wrtten but its not giving what I need.

```
[xml]$file = get-content ./O365IPAddresses.xml
$xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("/products/product")

    Foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {
        $o = New-Object Object

        Add-Member -InputObject $o -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $xmlProperty.name

        foreach ($p in $xmlProperty.addresslist)
        {
            $type += $p.type
            $add += $p.address
        }

        Add-Member -InputObject $o -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Type -Value $type
        Add-Member -InputObject $o -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Address -Value $add

        $type="";
        $add="";

        #Add-Member -InputObject $o -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $xmlProperty.name
        $o
    }

    $o="";
```

This is what i need the code to output.

```
Name    Type    V
Office  IPv4    12111,12121,12,12,1,2,12,1,2,
Office  IPv6    12111,12121,12,12,1,2,12,1,2,
Office  URL google, yahoo
lyo IPv4    12111,12121,12,12,1,2,12,1,2,
lyo IPv6    12111,12121,12,12,1,2,12,1,2,
lyo URL some lyn, yahoo
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried that was not really working? Right now this reads like a request for a code writing which is not what SO is here for.

Comment: Since you mention you dont know PS very well, I would HIGHLY suggest learning how to use the help function.  Type this into PS : `help *CSV*` and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but doing the Add-Member stuff will lead you into failure.  PowerShell is an object oriented language, so it's much better to just emit and object as you go through a chunk of code, and let PowerShell collect them all for you in the pipeline.

I've amended and truncated your code.  With this code:

```
$xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("/products/product")
$o = New-Object Object
    Foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {

        foreach ($p in $xmlProperty.addresslist)
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{Name=$xmlProperty.Name;Type=$p.type;Address=$p.address}

        }

    }
```

You'll get this output:

```
Name   Type Address                               
----   ---- -------                               
office IPv6 {2, 256, 434}                         
office IPv4 {13.107, 13.14/24}                    
office URL  {*.google, *.yahoo, *.some other link}
LYO    URL  {*.rtrt, eever}                       
LYO    IPv4 {23.178, 23.18, 23.19}                
LYO    IPv6 {2a01:13::/4, 2a01:1}
```

Which you can pipe into `Export-Csv` to make into a spreadsheet.

I want to draw attention to the `[pscustomobject]` notation.  This is a PowerShell v3 and up shorthand for creating a new object, which accepts a key-value pair of object property and values.  So, at this point in our for-each loop, we've got the variable `$p` defined, which has the following values:

```
type address              
---- -------              
IPv6 {2a01:13::/4, 2a01:1}
```

We're making a new object here, grabbing the `.Name` property of the parent object `$xmlProperty`, and then picking out the two extra values from `$p` we wanted to bring over as well.

Hope this helps.

## What to do about System.String[]

If one of your properties contains more than one values, then you'll get a weird output in your CSV file.  Essentially, PowerShell will scrape through the output, and rerender it in comma separated value format.  When a property has two values, PowerShell will list it as System.String[] or the full object name with `[]` appended at the end, which is notation for an array (object containing more than one item).

```
$xmlProperties = $file.SelectNodes("/products/product")
$o = New-Object Object
Foreach ($xmlProperty in $xmlProperties) {

    foreach ($p in $xmlProperty.addresslist)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{Name=$xmlProperty.Name;Type=$p.type;Address=$p.address}

    }

} | select Name, Type, @(N={Address};exp={$_.Address -join ','}}
```

Comment: `Add-Member` can still have its place. FWIW the OP was obviously trying to make objects. Much like everything in PowerShell there a many ways to do the same thing. Using `foreach` in the way you have mean you have to do something special to get the output piped or saved FYI.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Its exctly I was looking for.

Comment: Just a note, if you export to a csv, you'll end up with array characters in the export (so the column for addresses will list SystemArray[[]]), because there are multiple values for that row, and PowerShell doesn't know to handle that. If you run into that, look at using the -join command. I'll add a link to an example when I'm back on a pc later if you like

Comment: Added an example of how to handle the System.String[] characters in a CSV.